# session variables not accessible within views that make use of ajax requests

Tags: django, django-views

Through trial and error, I've provide that within my site, my views that make use of ajax requets don't have access to session variables when the site is not running on https.

```
def profile_update(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if 'blogowner' in request.session:
            user_id = request.session['blogowner']
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
```

My site servers my main site (which is https) and subdomains that are only http.
Do you know if there is a setting that may be preventing my ajax calls from accessing session variables when the site is only setup as http and not https?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE was set to True. Setting it to False got me around this.